# How to get the woocommerce credit card form data?

Tags: html, wordpress, post, woocommerce, payment-gateway

The woocommerce credit card form is added like this : 
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Payment_Gateway_CC.html#50-98

```
public function payment_fields() {
      $cc_form = new WC_Payment_Gateway_CC();
      $cc_form->id       = $this->id;
      $cc_form->supports = $this->supports;
      $cc_form->form();
}
```

but i have to pass the credit card details to API in order to get a response

```
    public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
      global $woocommerce;
      $customer_order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
      $order_data = $customer_order->get_data();
         $creditcardnumber = ??;
    }
```

How can get the credit card number and other details so that i can post it?

Comment: Hi...did you ever resolve this? I'm trying to figure the same thing out and am stuck.

Comment: @ChrisK. yes it's with  `$_POST['your-id-card-number']` and card-cvv, card-expiry. Could n't find any doc related to it. The better approach is to reverse coding an already exiting a plugin in wordpress repo with similar feature.

Comment: @ChrisK. which payment gateway you are working on?

Comment: I'm creating one under contract...and thank you. Was just about to try doing what you stated above :)

Answer (score 1):

It Works for me:

```
WC()->checkout()->getValue('your-id-card-number')
```